# How to enable VLAN access from WSL2 / Ubuntu on Windows 11

Tags: vlan, windows-11, wsl2

On a Windows 11 machine, I have enabled two VLANs an my Intel I210 Gigabit Network adapter, one untagged and one tagged VLAN2 using the Intel PROSet Adapter Configuration Utility.

The machine has WSL2 activated with Ubuntu as default system. However, in the Ubuntu shell, I cannot see VLAN2, but only the untagged network.

How can I enable VLAN access from WSL2?

Comment: This was an interesting read:   https://davidbombal.com/wsl-2-networking/   ..... I use Virtual Machines instead of WSL for detailed networking applications.

Answer (score 0):

While WSL2 is a virtualized environment, it's what I would call a "managed virtualized environment" where Microsoft handles the "plumbing", including and especially the networking.

There's actually a Linux VM running under the Hyper-V "engine" that you can't even see.  This is where the actual kernel is running.  The distribution that you use in WSL2 is then essentially placed into its own namespace inside that VM to isolate it (to some degree) from the other distributions and instances.

So you don't get a lot of control over the networking (or init, or other bootstrapping).

As @John mentioned in the comments, VMs where *you* can manage the networking are often better suited for this purpose.

However, if you really want to give it a try, there are some *possibilities*.  While [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/7395) was closed by Microsoft as being a duplicate (which it doesn't seem to be), a recent response there in the form of [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/7395) seems to provide a potential way to specify your own network switch for WSL.  I have not tried this myself.

It's also not clear to me whether you can use this to change the VLAN for the adapter, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the two adapters to two Hyper-V External Virtual Switches. Then you can use [the WSLAttachSwitch](https://github.com/dantmnf/WSLAttachSwitch)
 tool to have the adapters available as interfaces in WSL2.

Or check my other answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1670969/wsl2-make-available-visible-all-windows-network-adapters-inside-ubuntu/1836219#1836219).